# Pre order traversal issue in C: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT

Tags: c, pointers, recursion

I am learning C and data structure. Pre order traversal ,exactly.

```
typedef struct TreeNode{
    int data;
    struct TreeNode * leftChild, * rightChild;
}TreeNode ;

void pre_order_traversal(TreeNode *node){
    if(node != NULL){
        printf("%d", node->data);
        pre_order_traversal(node->leftChild);
        pre_order_traversal(node->rightChild);
    }
}

void node_example(void){
    struct TreeNode zero, one , five, seven , eight , nine;
    zero.data = 0;
    one.data = 1;
    five.data = 5;
    seven.data = 7;
    eight.data = 8;
    nine.data = 9;

    seven.leftChild = &one;
    seven.rightChild = &nine;

    one.leftChild = &zero;
    one.rightChild = &five;

    nine.leftChild = &eight;

    pre_order_traversal(&seven);
}
```

Here is the issue:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT

When executed in `printf("%d", node->data);`

I am not good at C pointer, either recursion in C.

I am not quite sure where the problem is.

Of course I googled, the code online I have found is too complicated for me. And I still try to understand it .

Any tip is quite welcomed.

Proper explanation is more than expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize dangling children to NULL before you access then:

```
TreeNode seven;
seven.data = 7;
seven.LeftChild = NULL;
seven.RightChild = NULL;
```

Do this with all TreeNodes you create. It will minimize errors for you. The general method is to create a constructor function that initializes tree nodes when called:

```
TreeNode *constructor(int data) {
    TreeNode *T = malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
    if (T == NULL) {
        /* Error */
    }
    T -> data = data;
    T -> LeftChild = NULL; T -> RightChild = NULL;
    return T;
}
```

I would also suggest working with pointers to TreeNode rather than allocating them on stack because it makes working with recursion slightly less cumbersome (my opinion).

Comment: Your opinion is nice.

Comment: great, I have a similar question, do hope you can do me a favor , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51851874/c-struct-construct-error-thread-1-exc-bad-access-code-1-address-0x0