# C++ node assign error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

Tags: c++, struct, construct

I am learning DSA , Linked List , new to C++.
My linked list is of exception.

Error Info:

[image: error]

It is much longer than it should be.

[image]

Here is my code:

define struct ListNode

```
// Definition for singly-linked list.
struct ListNode {
     int val;
     ListNode *next;
     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
 };
```

get Intersection of Two Linked Lists

```
 ListNode * Solution_three :: getIntersectionNode(ListNode *headA, ListNode *headB) {

    ListNode * p_one = headA;
    ListNode * p_two = headB;

    if (p_one == NULL || p_two == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    while (p_one != NULL && p_two != NULL && p_one != p_two) {
        p_one = p_one -> next;
        p_two = p_two -> next;


        if( p_one == p_two ){
            return p_one;
        }

        if (p_one == NULL) {
            p_one = headB;
        }
        if (p_two == NULL) {
            p_two = headA;
        }
    }
    return p_one;
}
```

construct samples and call Intersection of Two Linked Lists

```
void Solution_three :: test_Intersection(){

    ListNode *node_one = new ListNode(1);
    ListNode *two = new ListNode(3);
    ListNode *three =  new ListNode(5);
    ListNode *four =  new ListNode(7);
    ListNode *five =  new ListNode(9);
    ListNode *six =  new ListNode(11);

    node_one->next = two;
    two->next = three;
    three->next = four;
    four->next = five;
    five->next = six;


    ListNode *node_a_one = new ListNode(2);
    ListNode *a_two = new ListNode(5);
    ListNode *a_three = new ListNode(9);
    ListNode *a_four = new ListNode(19);
    node_a_one->next = a_two;
    a_two->next = a_three;
    a_three->next = a_four;


    ListNode node_r = *getIntersectionNode(node_one, node_a_one);
    printf("%d", node_r.val);
    cout<<"\n"<<node_r.val<<endl;
}
```

By take a break point, I see the linked list is much longer.

I don't know how to take it out.

Comment: `ListNode *node = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));` -- Undefined behavior.  Do not construct non-POD types using `malloc`.  Use `new`, not `malloc`.

Comment: Second, to get the intersecting node can be done by simply using an `unordered_set<ListNode*>`.  Just add all the nodes of the first list to the set.  Then for each node in the second list, check if it is in the set.  If that node is in the set, then that is the intersecting node.

Comment: Set is of power. Thanks for advice . This is LeetCode 160. Intersection of Two Linked Lists https://leetcode.com/problems/intersection-of-two-linked-lists/discuss/49789/My-accepted-simple-and-shortest-C++-code-with-comments-explaining-the-algorithm.-Any-comments-or-improvements

Comment: Could you give a little tip? @PaulMcKenzie  . I use `new`, and it still ...

Comment: If you go to the link, the "Solution" tab has a description using a hash table.  An `unoredered_set` is what is the hash table.

Answer (score 0):

How could `p_one != p_two` be true.

Should overload the operator `!=`, to compare the value of the node.